# Getting characteristic polynomial from a small matrix

Tags: matrices, number-theory, polynomials

Sorry I don't know how to format matrices, but if I have this matrix

$\pmatrix{1& 1& 0\\
    0& 0& 1\\
    1 &0& 1\\}$

How is the characteristic polynomial $λ^3 − 2λ^2 + λ − 1$? Is there some methodical approach to getting the characteristic polynomial from a matrix?

EDIT:

$\text{Det}(A - \lambda I)$ means

$\pmatrix{1-\lambda& 1& 0\\
    0& -\lambda& 1\\
    1 &0& 1-\lambda\\}$

and so the determinant of this matrix is

$= (1-\lambda)((-\lambda)(1-\lambda) - (1)(0)) - (1)((0)(1-\lambda)-(1)(1)) + (0)((0)(0) - (-\lambda(1)))$

$= -\lambda^3+2 \lambda^2-\lambda+1$

Huh, seems to be similar, but the signs are different?

Comment: That isn't the characteristic polynomial. Just take $\det({A-\lambda I})$

Comment: Exactly, you just have to compute the determinant of $A-\lambda I$.

Comment: Many authors define the characteristic polynomial as $\det(\lambda I - A)$, so that the result is always a monic polynomial.  The factor $-1$ difference in your version is not really important as the "characteristic roots" (eigenvalues) come out the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most elementary linear algebra courses you're looking for the characteristic polynomial as means to study the eigenvalues. Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$,  $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ if there exists $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$Av = \lambda v$$ But then we have $(A - \lambda I)v = 0$. By definition, $A-\lambda I$ is then not invertible and hence it has $0$ determinant. So the eigenvalues are the solutions to the equation $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$. The fact that the signs are different in your case doesn't matter: the solutions to any polynomial $p(x)=0$ are the same as the solutions to $-p(x)=0$.

Comment: Can you rephrase this in plain English as well? When you say "Given an n×n matrix A, A has eigenvalue λ∈ℝ if there exists v∈ℝ such that Av=λv" doesn't this mean $A = \lambda$? I don't understand what this is saying exactly

Comment: no, it does not mean that. $A$ is a matrix and $\lambda$ is a number. It means there's a vector $v$ such that $Av$ is a scalar multiple of $v$, and that multiple is $\lambda$. Essentially, your matrix acts on the vector by multiplying it by a constant.

Comment: As an example, consider the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$  and the vector $v = [0,1,0]^T$. We then have $Av = 2v$.

Comment: I had been confused by what you meant when you said $v$ was an element of $R^n$.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry. Just to clarify, yes, it is a $n \times 1$ column vector with entries in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you just find $\det(A-\lambda I)$ (or $\det(\lambda I-A)$ if you want the leading term positive).  Alternatively, if you find all of the (complex) eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$, counted with multiplicity, then the characteristic polynomial will be $(\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2)(\lambda-\lambda_3)$.  In this particular case you'll want to do the first method because the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ are pretty gnarly:

[image]

~ [*WolframAlpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%CE%BB%2B2+%CE%BB%5E2-%CE%BB%5E3&lk=1&rawformassumption=)